# Filtering an array of objects that contain arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

This is a smaller version of the array i have but it has the same structure

with const arr below, i want to create 2 new arrays with unique values that are sorted in ascending order

```js
const arr = [{
    tags: ['f', 'b', 'd'],
    weight: 7,
    something: 'sdfsdf'
  },
  {
    tags: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    weight: 6,
    something: 'frddd'
  },
  {
    tags: ['f', 'c', 'e', 'a'],
    weight: 7,
    something: 'ththh'
  },
  {
    tags: ['a', 'c', 'g', 'e'],
    weight: 5,
    something: 'ghjghj'
  }
];

const finalTags = [];
const finalWeight = [];

// TODO:  find a better way to do this
arr.forEach(v => {
  if (finalWeight.indexOf(v.weight) === -1) finalWeight.push(v.weight);
  v.tags.forEach(val => {
    if (finalTags.indexOf(val) === -1) finalTags.push(val);
  });
});

// Ascending order
finalTags.sort();
finalWeight.sort();
```

what i have above works, but seems a bit messy and was wandering if there was a better/tidier way of doing this

Comment: Might this be better off on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in order to get an object with the sorted arrays `{tags: [], weights: []}`:

```js
const arr = [{tags: ['f', 'b', 'd'],weight: 7,something: 'sdfsdf'},{tags: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],weight: 6,something: 'frddd'},{tags: ['f', 'c', 'e', 'a'],weight: 7,something: 'ththh'},{tags: ['a', 'c', 'g', 'e'],weight: 5,something: 'ghjghj'}];
const obj = arr.reduce((a, {tags, weight}) => {
  a.tags = [...new Set(a.tags.concat(tags))];
  a.weights = [...new Set(a.weights.concat(weight))];
  return a;
}, {tags: [], weights: []});

// final result i want
console.log('finalTags:', obj.tags.sort()); // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
console.log('finalWeight:', obj.weights.sort()); // [5, 6, 7];
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I will vote you up because you had a similar idea to mine and was first. However, it will be nice to see some explanation too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Shidersz. I have added a better description and you also have my up..

Comment: much nicer than my version, thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create two sets, one with the `tags` and other with the `weights`. After this you can transform the `sets` to `arrays` and use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on they:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    tags: ['f', 'b', 'd'],
    weight: 7,
    something: 'sdfsdf'
  },
  {
    tags: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    weight: 6,
    something: 'frddd'
  },
  {
    tags: ['f', 'c', 'e', 'a'],
    weight: 7,
    something: 'ththh'
  },
  {
    tags: ['a', 'c', 'g', 'e'],
    weight: 5,
    something: 'ghjghj'
  }
];

let res = arr.reduce((acc, {tags, weight}) =>
{
    acc.tags = new Set([...acc.tags, ...tags]);
    acc.weights.add(weight);
    return acc;
}, {tags: new Set(), weights: new Set()});

let sortedWeigths = [...res.weights].sort();
let sortedTags = [...res.tags].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
console.log("weights: ", sortedWeigths, "tags: ", sortedTags);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code. This basically splits `arr` up into `finalTags` and `finalWeights`.

[`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) flattens the array (`[1, [2, [3]]]` would become `[1, 2, 3]`)

`finalTags.filter((item, index) => finalTags.indexOf(item) >= index).sort();` remove's the duplicates.

```js
const arr = [{
    tags: ['f', 'b', 'd'],
    weight: 7,
    something: 'sdfsdf'
  },
  {
    tags: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    weight: 6,
    something: 'frddd'
  },
  {
    tags: ['f', 'c', 'e', 'a'],
    weight: 7,
    something: 'ththh'
  },
  {
    tags: ['a', 'c', 'g', 'e'],
    weight: 5,
    something: 'ghjghj'
  }
];

let finalTags = arr.map(e => e.tags);
finalTags = finalTags.flat();
finalTags = finalTags.filter((item, index) => finalTags.indexOf(item) >= index).sort();

let finalWeight = arr.map(e => e.weight);
finalWeight = finalWeight.filter((item, index) => finalWeight.indexOf(item) >= index).sort();

console.log(finalTags);
console.log(finalWeight);
```

**Sources:**

Removing duplicates: https://gomakethings.com/removing-duplicates-from-an-array-with-vanilla-javascript/